# Why there is no mkdir in MSYS?

Tags: netbeans, mingw, msys

Hello I've installed MinGW with Msys and there is no mkdir in bin folder of Msys.

Why?

How can I use Netbeans to compile C++ code?

I get such error
mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-Windows
make.exe[2]: mkdir: Command not found
when trying to compile in Netbeans 8.1

Answer (score 0):

Several commands are missing when installing MinGW and Msys.

E.g. when running the "/postinstall/pi.sh" as recommended in the "Getting started" guide, the following commands were missing:
- mkdir
- cp
- rm

I fixed it by downloading:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/?source=typ_redirect
and then copying the missing commands to C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin

Of course I did a search initially to see if the commands should hide anywhere else in the MinGW/Msys filetrees, and they didn't.

I also copied useful commands like:
- ls
- rmdir